# Detect tap on CCTableView cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, cocos2d-iphone

I am using a `CCTableView` to make a table with `CCNode`s as cells. Those `CCNode`s have a button each. I want to be able to detect if a user taps on a cell and if it taps on the button. But the `CCTableView` doesn't have a `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method so how can I do this? Do you know of any open source class that has this method?

P.S. I am using version 3 of cocos2d

Answer (score 0):

I took a different approach after trying numerous things

```
@interface WKTableCell : CCTableViewCell
@end

@implementation WKTableCell
- (instancetype) initWithTitle: (NSString *) title
{
    self = [super init];
    if (!self)
        return nil;
      [self.button setTitle:title];
      // This is a transparent png (400x200) for my needs
      CCSpriteFrame * frame = [CCSpriteFrame frameWithImageNamed:@"cell.png"] ;

      [self.button setPreferredSize:CGSizeMake(frame.originalSize.width, frame.originalSize.height)];
      [self.button setContentSizeType:CCSizeTypePoints];
      [self.button setBackgroundSpriteFrame:frame forState:CCControlStateNormal];
}
// then in your table

[table setBlock:^(id sender) {
    CCLOG(@"yup, this gets called.. ");
}];
```

this did work for me..

Answer (score -1):

Your `CCTableView`, responds to the `CCTouchDelegate`, so you can use `ccTouchBegan` etc
to detect the point and then calculate what cell there was in that point. Here the class reference:

http://docs.huihoo.com/doxygen/cocos2d-x/2.1.2/d0/d38/classcocos2d_1_1_c_c_touch_delegate.html

Comment: Is that the only option? I was looking for a more high level approach. Using the by using the `ccTouchBegan` I would have to implement all the logic to distinguish a tap from a user just scrolling the table or clicking on the button vs clicking on the cell etc..

Comment: I don't think there is many logic..you have just to know what cell is under the touch when touch is ended, and use a flag to know when touch is moving so that mean that users is dragging and you haven't to consider the touch as SELECT. For the other is the same, because at this point you will have the cell.